# Json Object from cshtml to controller using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a jquery function like this.

```
            var jsonArg = new Object();
            $(".x").each(function () {
                var val1 = "Domain:" + $(this).children(".y").html();
                var val2 = "shop:" + $(this).children(".z").html();

                jsonArg[val1] = val2;

            });
                 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Mappings",
                data: { "jsonArg": jsonArg  }
                })
```

Now I want to send value of jsonArg to my controller. 
My Controller looks like this,

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Mappings(string Json)
  {
          return null;
  }
```

I am getting null value in the controller.Please help.

Comment: use this `public ActionResult Mappings(string jsonArg)`

Comment: You are trying to serialize a string. you don't need to serialize it, you only need to serialize complex objects. Try sending "data: jsonArg,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change variable Name.

```
[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Mappings(string jsonArg)
   {
      return null;
   }
```

And Try JSON.stringify();

```
 data: { "jsonArg": JSON.stringify(jsonArg) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.But still getting null.

Comment: Try JSON.stringify();     data: { "jsonArg": JSON.stringify(jsonArg)  }

Comment: Good to hear, I updated my answer if you want to mark it answered.